# Why doesn't my variable save to my array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I have a piece of code that checks a value against an array and if that value is not found in the array, then it adds that value to another array (called the `soldListingArray`). It then saves the `soldListingArray` to the localStorage (using `localStorage.setItem("array", soldListingArray`). For some reason, in my `console` I can see that the variable is the correct one, after adding it to the array, but outside of the code when I call for the entire array, it says it's empty.

`array1` is the array I'm checking all the values inside against the `array2` array.

Here is my code:

```
    function checkToSeeIfListingIsSold() {

    var soldListingArray = localStorage.getItem("array");

    var x = 0;
    var y = array1.length;

    do {

        var index = array1[x];

        if (array2.indexOf(index) == -1) {

            // Here I add the variable to my soldListingArray

            soldListingArray[soldListingArray.length] = index;

            // Here my console says what has been added to the soldListingArray (the value is correct).

            console.value += index + " has been added to soldListingArray;\n";
            }

         x++;

        } while (x < y)

   localStorage.setItem("array", soldListingArray);

   // Here I ask my console to display my soldListingArray but I get an empty array back.

   console.value += "Sold Array: " + soldListingArray;

   }
```

Why wasn't the `index` variable added and saved to my `soldListingArray`?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: hmm... seems like you never converted `soldListingArray` to an array. When you pull it from localstorage, it is a string.

Comment: @KevinB - And then, technically, it behaves like an array of chars

Comment: Why don't you use `soldListingArray.push(index)` and `localStorage.push(soldListingArray);` ?

Comment: @Fenistil strings don't have a push method. :)

Comment: @LcSalazar Not in Javascript. In C, sure.

Comment: @KevinB No I actually already have saved an "a" into my `soldListingArray` (I saved it as an array) and when I call it, it displays the "a" but nothing else. Am I missing something though?

Comment: Oh sorry, because of sg. I thought that localStorage is also an array.. :(

Comment: @Nit - Js too: `"abcdef"[3] // = "d"`

Comment: @TheMan Right, but when you pull it from localstorage, it's a string. Localstorage can only store strings.

Comment: Oh...  Is there any other efficient way to store arrays on someones computer? Or do I have to convert my string to an array and back to a string?

Comment: array to string and then back again. Far easier than it sounds though.

Comment: @KevinB Ok. Like the answer below? Will my converted array still have the exact same values though?

Comment: Yes, exactly like the answer below.

Comment: @LcSalazar Strings don't offer a plethora of methods that arrays have. They're array-like but saying they're an array of chars is wrong.

Comment: @Nit - True... misspelled... I meant it may also be referenced by indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the array to a string if you want to use local storage:

`localStorage.setItem("array",JSON.stringify(soldListingArray))`

Then when you need to access it later and add items, you convert it back to an array:

`soldListingArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("array"));`

This has been answered before; a little research would go a long way:
[Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: Would this mess up my array at all?

Comment: Nope, you can stringify and parse over and over and over and you'll always get the value back exactly as it was before.

Comment: It wouldn't unless there's a problem with your code or how your array is formatted

Comment: Alright thanks this should work for me. I didn't know localStorage could only store strings. I used it once before to save integers but I guess that it did the conversion automatically then. Anyway thanks for clearing that up. I'll try out the code later tonight.